# $n\in N, a_{n+1} = a_n (1 - a_n)$ , $0 < a_0 < 1$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot n = 1$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$n\in N,   a_{n+1} = a_n  (1 - a_n)$ , $0 < a_0 < 1$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\cdot n = 1$. I proved that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and that $a_n$ is strictly decreasing. I tried Cezaro Stolz but didn't get anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow 1$.