# Recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_{n}^2$ with $x_1=1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_{n}^2$ with $x_1=1/2$, evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$$
And
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} nx_n$$
My attempt is this: $x_2=1/4$, $x_3=3/16$, $x_4=39/256$; the sequence seems to be decreasing, and by the recurrence I notice that $x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^2 \leq x_n$ so it is decreasing.

Then it has a limit $L$ and by the recurrence it must be $L=L-L^2\Leftrightarrow L=0$; hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =L=0$$
Don't know what to do for the second limit, because just evaluating it gives an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot0$.

Thanks.

Comment: If you list out $ n x_n$ for several values, what do you think the limit becomes?

Comment: This ia duplicate of [MSEq question 3087363](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087363) and several other duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inverse sequence $y_n=1/x_n$.
We can write the following:
$$
y_{n+1} = \frac1{x_{n+1}} = \frac1{x_n(1-x_n)} = \frac{y_n^2}{y_n-1} = y_n+\frac{y_n}{y_n-1}.
$$

Can you see how fast this thing is growing when $n\gg0$?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

At first, the sequence is decreasing since

$$x_{n+1}-x_n = -x_n^2\le 0$$

secondly, it is easy to prove by induction that

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;\;\; 0\le x_n \le 1$$

decreasing and bounded , it converges to $ L$.

$[0,1]$ is closed thus $L\in[0,1]$.

and $L$ satifies
$$L=L-L^2$$ because $ f : x\mapsto x-x^2$ is continuous at $ [0,1]$ and
$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n).$$

finally, $L=0$.